# Magento 2.4.1 products not shown in category

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.1

I have just migrated by my site form local to server and in the category the products are not visible, i have tried reindexing but not work also when i try to create any new product from backend am getting this is taking too long and error code is **504** while saving it

Also i have checked the logs and got this:-

> [2021-01-06 10:32:37] report.CRITICAL:
> {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
> shards
> failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[]},"status":503}
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException(code:
> 503):
> {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
> shards
> failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[]},"status":503}
> at
> /var/www/html/healthcare/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:665)"}
> []

**elastic search version = 7.9.2 and also when i test it form the backend it is succesfull.**

any fix for this. Thanks in advance

update:- also while searching for products am getting this error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException): {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[]},"status":503}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be an elastic-search version issue. Please try to downgrade the elastic-search version from 7.9 to 7.6.

Comment: are you sure about this as this is also mention in requirements but am not sure does 2.4.1 supports 7.9.2 version of ES?

Comment: Please check this https://prnt.sc/whinwd

Answer (score 0):

> Magento (2.4.1) is tested with Elasticsearch 7.6.x. You can use other
> versions at your discretion, but we recommend using the tested version
> of Elasticsearch.

See the following document for Magento 2 system requirements including Elasticsearch.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html